# what does it mean when weights of a layer is not normally distributed

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning

I plot all my weights of my neural network on tensorboard, I found that some

weights of some layer is normally distributed:

[image]

but, some are not.

[image]

what does this imply? should I increase or decrease the capacity of this layer?
Update:
My network is a LSTM-based netowrk. the non-normal distributed weights is the weights multiply with input feature,  the normal distributed weights is the weights multiply with states.

Comment: It implies nothing, you can't make conclusions on the distribution of the weights.

Answer (score 0):

one explanation base on convolutional networks might be this(I don't know if this is true for any other kind of artificial neural models or not), hence the first layer tries to find distinct small features weights are distributed very widely and network tries to find any useful feature it can, then in the next layers combination of these distinct features are used, which make sense to put a normal distribution of weights hence every one of the previous features are going to be part of a single bigger or more representative feature  in next layers.

but this was only my intuition I am not sure if this is the reason with proof now.

Comment: Ｉ don't get your point. and I update the question to provide more context.

Comment: I meant every layer in network is doing something like finding better features base on combination of previous layer features, and since the first layer is connected to raw input, there is no connection or meaning among the features of this layer, but after the first layer there is meaning in combination of features, and every one of them make a specific contribution in making the features of next layer, so this made sense to me if there is a harmony in weights of this layer.